# Non root user is not getting access port 80 while running dockerized application using AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I am trying to deploy my angular dockerized application using AWS Lamda. I already uploaded my Docker image to AWS ECR. And trying to use that image while creating Lambda function.

I choosed docker run time option to create lambda function. But when I am running I am getting the error that `nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "/var/cache/nginx/client_temp" failed (30: Read-only file system) in lambda`.

When I investigated , I got knew that its happening because I am running as non root account.

And my dockerfile looks like the following,

```
FROM node:latest as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build --prod

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/helloworld/ /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
```

But I still need to use port 80 for my application.
So how can resolve this error to use port 80 as AWS non root account ?

Comment: 1. You don't appear to be running a docker image that implements the Lambda runtime interface, so this is never going to work. 2. You are focusing on port `80` as being the problem, when the error message about the read-only file system is totally unrelated to the port.

Comment: It has to be Nginx *or* Lambda. It cannot be both. Once you understand this, decide which you want: server-based (with Nginx) or serverless (with Lambda).

Answer (score 2):

The question is: why are you attempting to use NGINX within a Lambda? What's your objective?
Lambda, [as per the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html), is:

> a compute service that lets you run code without provisioning or
> managing servers.
>
> runs your code on a high-availability compute infrastructure and
> performs all of the administration of the compute resources, including
> server and operating system maintenance, capacity provisioning and
> automatic scaling, and logging. With Lambda, all you need to do is
> supply your code in one of the language runtimes that Lambda supports.
>
> You organize your code into Lambda functions. **The Lambda service runs
> your function only when needed and scales automatically.**

Given this description, the underlying architecture is handled by AWS, following an "on-demand" model which suggests a stateless nature for nearly every call (that's not true, but let's simplify it). 
This includes the service exposure which, in a conventional non-serverless setup, is typically overseen by NGINX or Apache.

Given your existing containerized environment, the alternatives are either [ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) or [Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/). 
The choice depends on your application's structure. As a quick guideline: ECS is better suited for a Microservices Architecture, while Elastic Beanstalk is more apt for a straightforward web application.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Now I just started to learn AWS services which making lot of confusions and time consuming for me. I am started to learn ECS and Lambda recently. For my learning , I am trying to deploy using Lambda. So here If I am using ng build and serve commands directly by replacing nginx defintion, can I directly get result from 4200 or 8085 any of these? Just i have confusion in creating dockerfile.

Comment: I don't know exactly what are you trying to do, but Lambda is not used to "expose something on a given port". Is a serverless compute service where you provide only the code that should be executed in a serverless and stateless way. If you need to expose a simple application server try Elastic Beanstalk or even a simple EC2 Virtual Machine where you can install and expose everything you want.

Comment: I am trying to explore the Docker option from AWS Lambda. So If I need to deploy one angular application using dockerization , I have to define docker image there. here I am just trying to learn Dockerization method from AWS lambda.

Comment: Expose an angular application is not a correct use case to use Lambda. Take a look at the doc, and imagine a use case that can fit the need of a serverless environment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html